# Remove the partial check behavior of Infragistics webDataGrid BoundCheckBoxField

Tags: c#-4.0, infragistics, webdatagrid

I used Infragistics WebDataGrid , I have BoundCheckBoxField column, I want remove partial check behavior. only check and uncheck

I wrote following class ,

```
public class BooleanConverter : IBooleanConverter 
{
    public BooleanConverter()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public object DefaultFalseValue
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public object DefaultTrueValue
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public bool IsFalse(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return false;
        else
            return Boolean.Parse(value.ToString());
    }

    public bool IsTrue(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return false;
        else
            return Boolean.Parse(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

`
and I call it like this:

```
     ((BoundCheckBoxField)this.uwGrid.Columns["Approval"]).ValueConverter = new BooleanConverter();
```

`

But it is not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you figured it out by now, but there is a bug with your value converter class (assuming you want null to show as false). The IsFalse method should be like this:

```
public bool IsFalse(object value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return true;
    else
        return !Boolean.Parse(value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The bound checkbox displays whatever data is bound to it.  By default, for a boolean or nullable boolean field, it displays true as checked, false as unchecked, and null as partial.  That's the only time it should show up- if you have null data.

If you do not like that behavior, you can assign the column a different ValueConverter.  This would be a class that implements IBooleanConverter.  You would make it so that null becomes checked or unchecked.